# `No more subgoals, but there are non-instantiated existential variables` in Coq proof language?

Tags: coq

I was following (incomplete) examples in Coq 8.5p1 's reference manual in chapter 11 about the mathematical/declarative proof language. In the example below for iterated equalities (`~=` and `=~`), I got a warning `Insufficient Justification` for rewriting `4` into `2+2`, and eventually got an error saying:

> No more subgoals, but there are non-instantiated existential
>   variables:
>
> ?Goal : [x : R  H : x = 2  _eq0 : 4 = x * x
>           |- 2 + 2 = 4]
>
> You can use Grab Existential Variables.

Example:

```
Goal forall x, x = 2 -> x + x = x * x.
Proof. 
proof. Show.
let x:R. 
assume H: (x = 2). Show. 
have ( 4 = 4). Show.
~= (2*2). Show. 
~= (x*x) by H. Show.
=~ (2+2). Show. (*Problem Here: Insufficient Justification*)
=~ H':(x + x) by H.
thus thesis by H'.
end proof.
Fail Qed.
```

I'm not familiar with the mathematical proof language in Coq and couldn't understand why this happens. Can someone help explain how to fix the error?

--EDIT--
@Vinz

I had these random imports before the example:

```
Require Import Reals.
Require Import Fourier.
```

Comment: Could you add the `Require` or library you use to have such a syntax ?

Comment: Sorry I don't have a Coq 8.5 to test your script atm. Usually this happens when you manage to prove a goal but some metavariable (think holes with types, that you usually fill by solving a subgoal) was left un-instantiated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof would work for `nat` or `Z`, but it fails in case of `R`.

From the Coq [Reference Manual](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual013.html#sec499) (v8.5):

> The purpose of a declarative proof language is to take the opposite approach where intermediate states are always given by the user, but the transitions of the system are automated as much as possible.

It looks like the automation fails for `4 = 2 + 2`. I don't know what kind of automation uses the declarative proof engine, but, for instance, the `auto` tactic is not able to prove almost all simple equalities, like this one:

```
Open Scope R_scope.
Goal 2 + 2 = 4. auto. Fail Qed.
```

And as @ejgallego [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37943401/2747511) we can prove `2 * 2 = 4` using `auto` only by chance:

```
Open Scope R_scope.
Goal 2 * 2 = 4. auto. Qed.
(* `reflexivity.` would do here *)
```

However, the `field` tactic works like a charm. So one approach would be to suggest the declarative proof engine using the `field` tactic:

```
Require Import Coq.Reals.Reals.
Open Scope R_scope.
Unset Printing Notations.  (* to better understand what we prove *)
Goal forall x, x = 2 -> x + x = x * x.
Proof.
  proof.
  let x : R. 
  assume H: (x = 2).
  have (4 = 4).
  ~= (x*x) by H.
  =~ (2+2) using field.  (* we're using the `field` tactic here *)
  =~ H':(x + x) by H.
  thus thesis by H'.
  end proof.
Qed.
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that Coq's standard reals are defined in an axiomatic way.

Thus, `+ : R -> R -> R` and `*`, etc... are abstract operations, and will never compute. What does this mean? It means that Coq doesn't have a rule on what to do with `+`, contrary for instance to the nat case, where Coq knows that:

- `0 + n   ~> 0`
- `S n + m ~> S (n + m)`

Thus, the only way to manipulate `+` for the real numbers it to manually apply the corresponding axioms that characterize the operator, see:

https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Reals.Rdefinitions.html
https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Reals.Raxioms.html

This is what `field, omega`, etc... do. Even `0 + 1 = 1` is not probable by computation.

Anton's example `2 + 2 = 4` works by chance. Actually, Coq has to parse the numeral 4 to a suitable representation using the real axioms, and it turns out that 4 is parsed as `Rmult (Rplus R1 R1) (Rplus R1 R1)` (to be more efficient), which is the same than the left side of the previous equality.

Comment: Thanks! That was very helpful! Should've `Unset Printing Notations.` first thing after `Require Import Reals` :)